# Searching through 10.000 URL:s after a word (Battlefield 3 Battlelog)

Tags: search, web, gnu, wget

I was wondering if it's possible to search through ~10k of Battlelog URL:s for a keyword? The pages are not .html-pages, the URL looks like this: http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/9693602/1/369698400/.

If the pages were .html I could just use software like Orbit Downloader or something, maybe GNU's wget. But now there are no actual files (as far as I can tell) to download.

I want to search from http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/9698003/1/369698400/ to http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/show/9708877/1/369698400/, and of course I don't want it to be like a ddos-attack or something, I don't want to get banned.

Just returning the URL:s with matches will be sufficient, I don't need to process the information more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page processes JSON data. The JSON data URLs used here are:

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/loadplayerreport/9693602/1/369698400/

http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/battlereport/loadgeneralreport/9693602/1/

Comment: That's useful! Now how do I use that? I guess I could just download 10k files and then search through them with a simple C-program? Would that burden their servers perhaps?

Comment: Well, just load and process it - there are many frameworks for consuming JSON data for about any modern platform. I'm pretty sure that their servers should be A-OK with it, but I'm not sure about the legal side (I have nothing to do with Battlefield at all, never played it, don't know their terms of use).